# Extent Report for parallel testing- Xunit and specflow

Tags: selenium, c#-3.0, specflow, xunit, extentreports

We are having extent reports for reporting. There's already a hooks class for extent reports which , the reports run good if they are scheduled sequentially.  But if the test scenarios are executed parallel , the report doesn't generate. 
Is there anyway i could use the same hooks class for both parallel and sequential execution. If yes, how.

Comment: We are working on a specflow adapter which will be soon available allowing both sequential and parallel execution. Note: this would be version 4 only.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `[ThreadStatic]` attribute to your extent report fields in Hooks call. It gives you the thread specific variable and you will get the correct report.

```
[ThreadStatic]
private static ExtentTest scenario;
```

Comment: Can u pls little brief about this?